# parallel execution of 2 gatling scenarios - start 2nd scenario after some time

Tags: performance-testing, gatling

I am new to gatling, I am trying to parallely execute 2 scenarios, but I want 2nd scenario to be executed after some time. Is there a way that I can implement this? I tried something as below but didn't work.

val scn1 = scenario("file upload").exec(getFileUpload())
val scn2 = scenario("get datasetId").exec(getDataSetId()).pause(4)

setUp(scn1.inject(atOnceUsers(1)),scn2.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpConf)

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `nothingFor` to delay the injection profile of scn2, see [doc](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_setup/).

Comment: @har123 That's not how things work here. First please accept this answer to your question and then create a new dedicated question.